# С моста — ударение

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Есть песня из фильма тридцатых годов, и там такие строчки:

> Ты любовь мою бросила с м**о**ста
> В полноводную реку Иртыш

Именно такое ударение. Как вы думаете, это устаревший вариант ударения или просто сделали так, чтобы ритмически нормально звучало?

Comment: Я страдала-страданула — 
/С м**о**ста в речку сиганула./
Из тебя , из дьявола/
Три часа проплавала...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 У тебя светло и просто.
 Не гони меня туда,
 Где под душным сводом мо́ста
 Стынет грязная вода.
 А. А. Ахматова, «Здравствуй! Легкий шелест слышишь…»

 Два берега с мо́стом понтонным
 глядят, как редут на редут.
 На левом, заливистом, тонут.
 На правом спасатели ждут.
 А. А. Вознесенский, Шуточная песенка о спасательной 
 станции
```

**ОТВЕТ**

```
 Ты любовь мою бросила с мОста
 В полноводную реку Иртыш.
```

1. Существительное ***мост*** относится к акцентной группе с **постоянным** ударением на окончании (в ед. и мн. числе). Отклонение возможно, но, как я думаю, **не для всех** грамматических форм. Значит, вариант ***с мОста*** не запрещен?
2. В словаре **Зализняка** указаны разрешенные предложные формы, причем там возможен перенос ударения не только на основу, но и **на предлог**. Также обратим внимание на **окончание У** с обстоятельственным значением. Интересно посмотреть на употребление этой формы **на практике,** прежде всего в стихотворениях других поэтов.
3. Я бы сделала такой вывод (в качестве версии). **Не все** предложные формы  подходят для переноса ударения на основу — некоторые из них звучат совершенно **неприемлемо** (на мОсту, например).

Перенос обычно делается для беспредложного управления — под сводом  **мОста**  или  для  предложного Т.п. — **с мОстом** понтонным, где в большей степени проявляется **предметное,** а не обстоятельственное значение существительного.

4. И тогда сочетание **сбросить (с чего?) с моста** в форме Р.п. **возможно,** но ударение в таких случаях желательно **обозначить.**

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

**[Ответы справочной службы](https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/291268), вопрос №291268**

**Мост** — это **в основном** группа с **постоянным ударением на окончании:** мостА – мостОв. Это **односложные** существительные, и фонетически здесь возможны **три** акцентные группы: (1) Ударение только на основе ( знАка - знАков): (2) Ударение только **на окончании** (дворА – дворОв): (3) Переход ударения с основы на окончание (рЯда – рядОв).

**[Склонение и ударение](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82)** **в слове «мост» (по Зализняку)**

м, 1b//1c, П₂(на) ✧ **пО мосту//по мОсту//по мостУ; зА мост//за мОст; нА мост//на мОст; **под мостОм//под мОстом//пОд мостом;** за мостОм//за мОстом//зА мостом.

Comment: Спасибо! Не все предложенные или падежные формы (пункт 3)?

Comment: Спасибо за приемку ответа, пришлось подумать. У меня предложные формы (то есть с предлогами), с ними проблема. У Зализняка указан список, но он скорее неполный. Однако формы на мОсту там нет, значит, не все подходят. Вероятно, надо выбирать  с пониманием, руководствуясь чувством языка.  Ну и в целом перенос ударения на основу должен быть обоснованным.

Comment: Sharon, у вас в "Ответах справочной службы, вопрос №291268" как бы нет ни самого вопроса, ни ответа, а просто информация-размышления спрашивающего. Это так задумано? // И в самом конце надо бы ударение поменять на предлог (зА мостом), а то два одинаковых получилось.

Comment: Ха-ха, Саш, исправил, а потом прочитал ваше сообщение. Про отсутствие вопроса тоже задумался. Шарон, понятно теперь про предложные формы в смысле, что с предлогами, не додумался до этого, подумал про предложный падеж. :))

Comment: Артём, ну и хорошо!

Answer (score 1):

Если верить [Грамоте](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82&mode=all&l=1), то такое ударение допустимо.

> МОСТ, мост**а** и допуст. старш. м**о**ста, на мост**у**, но о м**о**сте и о мост**е**,
> мн. мост**ы**, мост**а**м; в сочетаниях с некоторыми предлогами в определённых
> значениях может произноситься двояко: с ударением на предлоге в
> соответствии со старшей нормой или с ударением на существительном в
> соответствии с младшей нормой, напр.: п**о** мосту и по мост**у** (идти и т.
> д.), н**а** мост и на м**о**ст (въехать и т. д.).

Comment: Спасибо! Вот и отлично!